# Remove filename from URLs

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pdf, url, find

I need to remove just filename (Ex.: 'number.pdf') from a URL:

1. http://URL.com/S01/000/users/info/4512.pdf
2. http://URL.com/S0152/01009/users/old/info/007401.pdf
3. http://URL.com/S45012/0000/users/info/14.pdf
4. http://URL.com/S450101/0/users/new/info/7895409.pdf
5. http://URL.com/S01/0000/users/info/1045.pdf
6. http://URL.com/S004/9082-00/users/areas-latam-co/info/65471.pdf
7. http://URL.com/S004/9082-246/users/areas-us/info/1530.pdf

Finally, I'd like get just this:

1. http://URL.com/S01/000/users/info/
2. http://URL.com/S0152/01009/users/old/info/
3. http://URL.com/S45012/0000/users/info/
4. http://URL.com/S450101/0/users/new/info/
5. http://URL.com/S01/0000/users/info/
6. http://URL.com/S004/9082-00/users/areas-latam-co/info/
7. http://URL.com/S004/9082-246/users/areas-us/info/

How Can i do it?

Any idea? Who say I?

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: Nothing yet because I'm very noob with python and I'd to learn little by little here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with `os.path.dirname()`.

Example:

```
import os

print(os.path.dirname('http://URL.com/S01/000/users/info/4512.pdf'))
```

Output:

```
http://URL.com/S01/000/users/info
```